# Advice for better logic

Tags: c#, logic

Currently, I am doing a performance improvement for the code of an old project written by someone who had been long gone (I mean left the company).
The code I want to improve is:

```
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
DataTable dtSourceTemp = new DataTable();
dtSource = GetData();
dtSourceTemp = dtSource.Copy();

foreach (DataRow item in dtSource.Rows)
{
    if (Functions.parseString(item["COL_1"]).Equals("NG"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow itemTemp in dtSourceTemp.Rows)
        {
            if (Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_1"]).Equals(Functions.parseString(item["PK_1"]))
                && Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_2"]).Equals(Functions.parseString(item["PK_2"]))
                && Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_3"]).Equals(Functions.parseString(item["PK_3"])))
            {
                itemTemp["COL_1"] = "NG";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is that the data have 4 primary keys (PK_1, PK_2, PK_3, PK_4).
PK_1 to 3 will define the series of item, and PK_4 will be the number of item in the series.

If any item within the series is NG, all items in the series are NG.

As for the above code, with around 80K records each time this code runs, there will be 6.400.000.000 loops to update (if each series has at least 1 NG item) 80.000 rows, which is extremely inefficient.

Can anyone give me an advice how to improve this?

Please note that all of this work is to display desired data to screen (dtSourceTemp will be the Datasource), not to actually update data in database.

**UPDATED:**

After thinking, this is what I think will run better:

```
DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
DataRow[] drSource = dtSource.Select("COL_1 = 'NG'");

foreach(DataRow dr in drSource)
{
    string pk1 = dr["PK_1"].toString();
    string pk2 = dr["PK_2"].toString();
    string pk3 = dr["PK_3"].toString();

    //TO-DO:Code to update data in dtSource based on 3 PK
    //Something equal to SQL Script "Update tbl set COL_1 = 'NG' WHERE ...."
}
```

However, I am currently stuck at updating the data of dtSource, as C# seem not to have any function for DataTable that can do the thing I want.

Comment: I think I agree with Mitch if I read it correctly -- move this whole thing to SQL. No reason for the code.

Comment: Sorry, no DB change. My boss does not want to touch the database, only allow to update the source code.

Comment: @Mitch: if this can be done in a single Select SQL script, it will be better. the select SQl for this data is simply "SELECT* FROM tbl"

Comment: I mean I am not allow to touch the database, but if what you mean is changing the SELECT script, then it is allowed, as the script is RAW SQL inside the code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to optimize since you are using basic loops and cannot move this to the database.

With that said, you can try to tweak certain things and I will take this opportunity to throw out that this should probably be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

**1 - Functions.parseString**

First thing that would actually cause a bottleneck is whatever `Functions.parseString()` is doing. That should be the first thing to look at and start writing unit tests to determine a baseline and measure the speed of 10,000 parses vs. whatever changes you think will make it faster.

**2 - Change The Order Of Your `If` Conditions**

Depending on the data that is actually stored, you could create a speed increase by changing the order up so it short circuits faster.

If your `PK_#` columns are something like `A,B,1 | A,B,2 | A,B,3` and so on, it would be better to change the order to check for `PK_3` first before the other items so it isn't calling `parseString` 4 times the majority of the time when PK_3 won't match. Basically, try to order it by the most unique value first.

**3 - Cache Some Values**

Why parse something for every item when it will always be the same?

```
foreach (DataRow item in dtSource.Rows)
{
    if (Functions.parseString(item["COL_1"]).Equals("NG"))
    {
        var pk1 = Functions.parseString(item["PK_1"])
        var pk2 = Functions.parseString(item["PK_2"])
        var pk3 = Functions.parseString(item["PK_3"])

        foreach (DataRow itemTemp in dtSourceTemp.Rows)
        {
            if (Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_1"]).Equals(pk1)
                && Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_2"]).Equals(pk2)
                && Functions.parseString(itemTemp["PK_3"]).Equals(pk3))
            {
                itemTemp["COL_1"] = "NG";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**4 - Run a SQL Query Instead Of Code**

(Untested MSSQL Example)

```
UPDATE YT
SET YT.COL_1 = 'NG'
FROM YOUR_TABLE YT
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
       FROM YOUR_TABLE YT2
       WHERE YT2.COL_1 = 'NG' 
         AND YT.PK_1 = YT2.PK_1 
         AND YT.PK_2 = YT2.PK_2 
         AND YT.PK_3 = YT2.PK_3
)
```

---

There's not much else you can really do. What you have is super basic and for the most part completely dependent on the processor that procedure is running on.

Comment: I do not have to use loop here. I can delete this block of code and write any code that can achieve the same result.

Comment: @N.D.H.Vu I didn't say there was anything wrong with a loop and no matter what, you are going to need some form of loop to do what you want.